# PHP POST data showing as 'ON' instead of numerical 1

Tags: php, html, post, radio-button

I am posting a value from a radio button , its value is 1 , but when I echo var_dump($_POST) , then it shows as "on" instead of 1 . Please help. I need to get 1 instead of "on".

```
<input type="radio" id = "item" value="<?php echo $ItemID[0]; ?>" 
name="ItemID"><label for="ItemID"><?php echo $ItemIDName[0]; ?></label>
```

**BROWSER GENERATED HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id = "ITEMA" 
value="1" name="ITEM"><label for="ITEMA">A</label>


<input type="radio" id = "ITEMB" value="2" checked="checked" name="ITEM" ><label for="ITEMB">B</label>

<input type="radio" id = "ITEMC" value="3" name="ITEM" >
<label for="ITEMC">C</label>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML

Comment: Please also show the PHP you've used to attempt this yourself first.

Comment: You must have "on" as a value somewhere. Show your HTML

Comment: @Jleagle : i have posted my html code

Comment: @sqlchild — No, you've posted your PHP. Fetch the page with your browser, view source and show us what the HTML generated by the PHP looks like.

Comment: You need to make the `for` and `id` attribute values match. Also not that `id`s must be unique, you can't give every radio button the same id.

Comment: @Quentin : sir, have posted the browser generated html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value for radio button is **"on"** ! Check your php code `$ItemID[0]` if it's really  being set to **1** !

Comment: if it's really set to **1** then post array will definitely have **1** as value. Are there any other radio elements being submitted or just this one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value for the radio button to something like `value="1"`, it will only be used when checked

> The value setting defines what will be submitted if checked.